# Convert String to LocalDateTime

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-security

I have an error in registration of tasks because the time must be converted from `String` to `LocalDateTime` and I don't know how to convert.

Below is my `Task` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "task", schema = "public")
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    private String date;

    @NotEmpty
    private LocalDateTime startTime;

    @NotEmpty
    private LocalDateTime stopTime;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(length = 1000)
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_EMAIL")
    private User user;

    public Task() {
    }

    public Task(String date, LocalDateTime startTime, LocalDateTime stopTime, String description, User user) {
        this.date = date;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.stopTime = stopTime;
        this.description = description;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Task(String date, LocalDateTime startTime, LocalDateTime stopTime, String description) {
        this.date = date;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.stopTime = stopTime;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(LocalDateTime startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getStopTime() {
        return stopTime;
    }

    public void setStopTime(LocalDateTime stopTime) {
        this.stopTime = stopTime;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

In `TaskController` class I have that function to register Tasks in the database:

```
@PostMapping("/addTask")
public String addTask(@Valid Task task,
                      BindingResult bindingResult,
                      HttpSession session,
                      @RequestParam("datetime")
                      @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSZ") LocalDateTime dateAndTime) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        return "views/taskForm";
    }

    String email = (String) session.getAttribute("email");
    taskService.addTask(task, userService.findOne(email));

    return "redirect:/users";
}
```

And in `TaskService` is the function for adding tasks in `TaskController`:

```
public void addTask(Task task, User user) {
    task.setUser(user);
    taskRepository.save(task);
}
```

Please can someone resolve this error:

> Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required
>   type java.time.LocalDateTime for property startTime; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed
>   to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type
>   [@org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty
>   java.time.LocalDateTime] for value 09:00; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value
>   [09:00]

and this:

> Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required
>   type java.time.LocalDateTime for property stopTime; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed
>   to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type
>   [@org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty
>   java.time.LocalDateTime] for value 18:00; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value
>   [18:00]

I have spent many days and I cannot resolve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And how does your input string for `dateAndTime` look like?

Comment: @mrkernelpanic look like mm:HH AM/PM

Comment: Why did you remove the request param from the question?? BTW I meant the actual value of `dateAndTime `

Comment: @mrkernelpanic I put it again because the patern in the reques is not like that I have used in front-end

Comment: Just send "10/11/2018 09:00" and your problem will be solved. You can't convert  a string time without the date to LocalDateTime. why do you need the column date if you already have startTime and stopTome as LocalDateTime?

Comment: If I make like String, surely the data will be stored, but I am making something else. I register tasks in the db, but I am making a comparisons of endTime and time.now(). If time().now is bigger than endTime, the task will be deleted automatically. For this task I am using cron jobs.

Comment: @FabioPlaka you just need to send datetime as "11.10.2018 09:00:00". You cant convert a string time to LocalDateTime because it doesn't have the date. You need to add the date

Answer (score 2):

You can write a converter to convert from a `String` to `LocalDateTime` and vice versa.

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateTimeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, String> {

    private final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime locDate) {
        return (locDate == null ? null : formatter.format(locDate));
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(String dateValue) {
        return (dateValue == null ? null : LocalDateTime.parse(dateValue, formatter));
    }
}
```

If you want to define a converter for each variable use

```
@Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
private LocalDateTime stopTime;
```

Comment: I will try once

Comment: It is a class itself. If `(autoApply = true)` is set JPA will covert all attributes if not you have to specify the converter on the variable as above.

Comment: I use that class and also I defined the converter for each variable that I want to use but I gives me that error:

**Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required LocalDateTime parameter 'datetime' is not present**

Comment: It doesn't look like the original problem. This problem seems to be pointing to your Rest endpoint mapping `@RequestParam("datetime")`.

Comment: I still haven't understand the problem

Comment: You have two problems here. The first one is the one you asked about in this thread (converting LocalDateTime to String and vice versa). The second one is the one you mentioned in the comments (`org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required LocalDateTime parameter 'datetime' is not present `). The second one is related to you Rest end point, it looks like when your making the call to `/addTask` the input request parameter for `@RequestParam("datetime")` is missing.

Comment: I solved the second problem but the first problem I haven't solved yet

Answer (score 1):

Use below to convert the time from String to LocalDateTime, but make sure you are getting the time in String form.

```
String str = "2018-12-10 12:30";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
```

Comment: in which class?

Comment: Use it in any Utility class create a method and use above code and expose it as public static, for example.